# AutoIT every 60 seconds execute function

Tags: autoit

I use AUTOIT and KODA to build a GUI, and I have a function to move a file.

I want to execute `CopyFile($sFilePath, $dFilePath, $FileFilter, $LastWriteSec)` function automatically every 60 seconds, and also when I click "test" button then the `CopyFile($sFilePath, $dFilePath, $FileFilter, $LastWriteSec)` function is executed.

I tried using `SELLP()` but it makes the other buttons inactive.

This my code, can anyone teach me how to do that?

```
#Region ### START Koda GUI section ### Form=
...
#EndRegion ### END Koda GUI section ###

Func CopyFile($sFilePath, $dFilePath, $FileFilter, $LastWriteSec)
...
EndFunc


While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    CopyFile($iniFromPath,$iniToPath, $iniFileKey, $iniLastWriteSec)
    Sleep(6*1000)
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $close
            Exit
        Case $minimum
            WinSetState("[TITLE:LogUpload]", "", @SW_MINIMIZE)
        Case $test
            CopyFile($iniFromPath,$iniToPath, $iniFileKey, $iniLastWriteSec)
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVKBq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVKBq.png)

Comment: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/guiref/GUIRef_OnEventMode.htm

Comment: Use `AdlibRegister()` for timed periodic tasks. ("every n seconds call func")

Comment: @Stephan AdlibRegister() can't send parameters to func? My function "CopyfIle" need to send parameters to it. Or can you give me a example?

Comment: @garbb I can't understand how to use OnEventMode, can you give me a example?

Comment: Look at GUI Reference - OnEvent Mode in the autoit help file, it provides several examples.

Comment: That's correct, but you can call a function without parameters that calls your function with parameters (or use global variables).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Sleep, that in essence pauses your entire script for the duration which is why your buttons don't work.

You are looking for something like this:

```
#Region ### START Koda GUI section ### Form=
...
#EndRegion ### END Koda GUI section ###

While 1
    CopyFile($sFilePath, $dFilePath, $FileFilter, $LastWriteSec)
    Local $timer = TimerInit() ;Begin a timer
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    While TimerDiff($timer) < 60 * 1000 ;If timer is less than 60 secs, begin looping Switch (wait for action or 60 secs elapsed)
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $close
            Exit
        Case $minimum
            WinSetState("[TITLE:LogUpload]", "", @SW_MINIMIZE)
        Case $test
            ExitLoop ;Bail out of loop (back to top, copyfile and restart timer)
    EndSwitch
    WEnd
WEnd
```

I am not available to test this but I am pretty sure it should work. However without understanding your full code I can't be better assistance. I don't know how you're storing the CopyFile parameters or how you want to use them.